# What Exception to throw when a branch should in theory be impossible to reach?

Tags: c#, exception, compilation

Like in this example:

```
public MatchResult GetResult(int home, int away)
{
    if ( home == away )
        return MatchResult.Draw;
    else if ( home > away )
        return MatchResult.HomeWins;
    else if ( home < away )
        return MatchResult.AwayWins;

    throw new Exception("Should be impossible");
}
```

I know I could fix this with an `else` for the last statement, but I often prefer to be explicit. Of course this is a simplified situation for example purposes.

Next to that: is the reason why the compiler throws `not all code paths return a value`, because the situation is too complicated for the compiler or because for other reasons (like we can *in theory* change the value of `home` midway by unmanaged code from a different thread or something?)

Comment: I can´t see how compiler generates that error from your code, as all branches have a return-value or at least htrow an exception. However your first question is quite opinion-based and will thus be closed. Anyway: how could a parameter neither be equal, greater or smaller another? How do you think it´s possible to reach the exception at all?

Comment: Having said this code-analysis-tools such as ReSharper will probably mark your exception-code as unreachable and you should delete it.

Comment: ReSharper won't detect this either, just tested it.

Comment: The situation isn't really too complicated, but the compiler is deliberately conservative. Even something trivial like `int a = 1; if (a > 0) return 0;` with nothing else in the method will be flagged, even though the code obviously always returns. The exact rules for this are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#end-points-and-reachability).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Indeed, ReShaper strugglses on the fact that we have only `if`-statements. Deleting the `if` from the last `else` will make it find the issue.

Comment: I'd rather rewrite this to say `if home > away return HomeWins else if away > home return AwayWins` and if it passes through that if/else block just return `Draw`

Comment: All of the `else` statements are redundant anyway, which Resharper would flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 7 [`UnreachableException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.unreachableexception?view=net-7.0) has been added.

Before .NET 7, I think the best solution is to copy [the code of the `UnreachableException` class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Diagnostics/UnreachableException.cs) into you project, and when you update to .NET 7 you can remove this class, without changing any line used by this class.

Answer (score 3):

> I know I could fix this with an else for the last statement, but I often prefer to be explicit.

You can remain explicit without telling the compiler. Since the only reason to be explicit is to help human readers, a comment in place of the actual `if` gives you the best of both worlds: programmers see the condition, while compilers don't bother you with unnecessary `throw`s or `return`s.

```
if ( home == away )
    return MatchResult.Draw;
else if ( home > away )
    return MatchResult.HomeWins;
else // if ( home < away )
    return MatchResult.AwayWins;
```

In situations where you genuinely need to throw an exception because some branch is impossible to reach the best course of action is to use assertions:

```
if (!CheckNonNegative(arg)) {
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(arg));
}
...
if (arg == 0) {
    ... // Do something
} else {
    Debug.Assert(arg > 0, "Method has checked arg to be non-negative");
    ... // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the last example still throw compilation errors when we the compiler expects a return value?

Comment: @DirkBoer If you are asking whether or not an assertion could be used in place of a `throw`, the answer is "no", because assertions are off in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that (if an exception *is* to be thrown - I'd rather change the code) this should throw a [`NotSupportedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception(v=vs.110).aspx). Generally, this is the exception to throw if a method is called but the current state of the object doesn't support the method call at that time.

It's only a short stretch to say that, if the laws of logic have broken down, you're in an unsupported state and cannot complete the method.